# Use Google Sign-in Button to authenticate users without sever

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-api

Google provides a simple sign-in button:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#before_you_begin

This button calls a function, "onSignIn" on successful login as such

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

I am thinking about calling one of my APIs inside "onSignIn" function and generate a token and save in users' browsers. Next time when users send API requests, I plan on using these tokens in the header to verify API access.

Is this a legitimate way of using this Google widget? Or I actually have to use OAuth and such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, you would not need the additional complexity of token generation at your API endpoints as the Google [ID tokens](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) facilitates your exact need.

Hence consider sending the user's ID token to your API and then, on the server, [verify the integrity](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#verify-the-integrity-of-the-id-token) of the ID token to accredit the user authority.

Moreover, if you require association of additional information with each user session/account the same architecture can be used with a supplementary database. For a more comprehensive guide refer [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#create-an-account-or-session) article.